# How to get hair fragments off of skin after beard trimming

Tags: personal-care, shaving

I thought I would be able to find an answer to this Googling but have been entirely unable to. Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology. Basically any time I trim my beard with my electric trimmer, small fragments of hair end up all over my hands, arms, neck. I can't find any good way of getting them off, it's like they're statically charged and stuck to my skin. Any tips?

Comment: I used to own a beard trimmer with a built-in vacuum.  It caught nearly all of the small fragments of hair. (I'm not posting this as an answer because there may still be a few flyaway hair fragments that land on your skin.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trimming right before taking a shower seems to help for me, but it isn't always an option.

A lint roller might work, especially if you were in a hurry. I've used one many times to get human and animal hair off of clothes and fabrics. I wouldn't recommend it if you have sensitive skin or are allergic to any adhesives though. 
[Lint rollers at Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/c/kp/lint-rollers)

Comment: This is not a bad idea. Might have to give it a shot

Comment: it works, better than anything else I'd tried anyway!

Comment: I use lint roller after haircuts to reduce the hairs going into my shirt, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

I use a cordless trimmer in the shower with a mirror attached to the shower wall. After I trim my beard, I simply take a shower; a sprayer attachment makes this even easier. This was done mainly to prevent the nasty cleanup of small hairs all over the vanity in the bathroom, but has worked out very nicely for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've always tied a towel around my neck and secured the other end somewhere in front of me. Because the towel is raised up to about shoulder level in front, this should reduce the amount of hair that lands on you by a healthy amount.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you can try your hair dryer in order to push them off. 
Or you can shave while taking shower, so the water will wash away the hairs.